# Splitting pins on USB-C

Tags: microcontroller, usb, display, protocol

I’m new to EE and I have a project I’m working on that has confused me.  I have an old display from a laptop that I want to make into a custom 2nd monitor, I bought a driver board for that model display. It has hdmi for the input and a separate dc jack for the 12v 2A power input. I am wondering if there is a way to get a usb c cable and split the lines to the hdmi port and get a negotiation board to ask for the 12v from my laptop usb c port.  Would the protocols for hdmi and usb c line up if I require the data lines from the usb c cable and require the power lines to power the board.  I’m not afraid to learn what I need to learn. I would really love to use a single usb c for power/data transmission instead of two separate wires.  Any information greatly helps me. Here is a link to the board https://www.ebay.com/itm/LCD-LED-controller-board-kit-DIY-HDMI-VGA-DVI-for-LTN156AT34-LTN156AT36-1366X768-/153148696996
If I can’t split the lines, how hard would it be for me to make my own usb receiver/hdmi converter. I have basic programming skills and can learn anything I need to for this project. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.mouser.com/applications/usb-type-c-adds-hdmi/ It's not a trivial project. You would need to be able to communicate in order to trigger the USB HDMI alt mode. And you need 12V 2A (or more) so it's 24W. The MacBook Pro only allows 15W output on Thunderbolt 3 equipped USB C ports. Other brands may allow more or less. So even if you could get the protocol, you don't have the power available.

Comment: How would I be able to check if I can get the 24W? Assuming I can, could I use a zy12pdn negotiator to get the power.  But how would I go about connecting the data lines to the corresponding hdmi data lines? Are there any beginner sources for making a device for usb c as in how to set up the protocol and stuff.

Comment: Usb C isn't exactly a beginners type project. A lot is locked behind industry pay walls like the hdmi consortium.

Comment: There are LCD driver boards already with built-in Type-C Alt-DP interface. I believe I saw one.